# Error: Cannot find module './utils/logger'

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

While running node.js, I am getting the following error message:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.14
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './utils/logger'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js
- C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\models\user.js
- C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\models\index.js
- C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\config\passport.js
- C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\deep7\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\SQL-Study\node_modules\sequelize\lib\data-types.js:10:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\deep7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\SQL-Study\\node_modules\\sequelize\\lib\\data-types.js',
    'C:\\Users\\deep7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\SQL-Study\\models\\user.js',
    'C:\\Users\\deep7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\SQL-Study\\models\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\deep7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\SQL-Study\\config\\passport.js',
    'C:\\Users\\deep7\\OneDrive\\Documents\\GitHub\\SQL-Study\\app.js'
  ]
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Please help me find a permanent solution. I have no idea what is causing this issue. My hunch was something could be wrong with sequelize since it's pointing it's one of lib. I tried uninstalling sequelize, sequelize-cli but that didn't help me in this case.

Comment: Try `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm i`? Sometimes installations are corrupted

Comment: I performed those actions, but it didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably something is corrupted in node_modules folder. Its better  to install the npm again, remove the old node_modules and install them again. This should fix your problem

```
npm install -g npm@latest
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```